# How to fetch auto generated document id in firebase firestore in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

how can I get this random generated document's ID? Thank you for your help

Comment: You mean after you added a new one or ?

Comment: Either you remember at the time it was added in your code, or you query for it based on the contents of the document.  Without seeing your code and understanding what you're trying to accomplish, it's hard to give advice.  Please edit the question to be more clear.

Answer (score 9):

You can get the `documentId` when adding the document:

```
  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").add(
  {
    "name" : "john",
    "age" : 50,
  }).then((value){
    print(value.id);
  });
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're trying to read from Firestore, you get the entire collection by doing
`db.collection("users")` and then you loop through the returned `querySnapshot` for each document returned. You can get the `documentID` that way. [Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_all_documents_in_a_collection)'s the documentation for it.

```
db.collection("users").get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
        var id = doc.id; // randomly generated document ID
        var data = doc.data(); // key-value pairs from the document
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give an accurate answer with seeing your code but here is an option:

```
StreamBuilder(
            stream: Firestore.instance
                .collection("cars")
                .snapshots(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
              } 
              else {
                  print(snapshot.data.documents[0].documentID) //this prints the document id of the (0th) first element in the collection of cars
               }
              })
```

You can use listview-builder to make a list and in the `itemCount:` property, you can use `snapshot.data.documents.length` and use `index` to access IDs of all elements in the following way: `snapshot.data.documents[index].documentID`