# This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used(flutter, firestore)

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I keep getting this error because I'm trying to save the document id inside the document. The sub collection function is meant to automatically create a sub collection. How do I get rid of this error?

```
Future<String?> addCollection(Username, groupName, location, postText) async {
   String id = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('groups').doc().id;
  CollectionReference collection =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('groups');
  var result = await collection.doc(id).set({
    'groupName': groupName,
      'groupChatId': id,
      'creator': Username,
      'testmember': [],
      'location': location,
    });
  await subcollection(id: result.id);
  return 'Created';
}

Future<String?> subcollection({required id}) async {
  CollectionReference collection =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('groups');
  collection.doc(id).collection('posts').add({'name': 'the'});
  return 'Created';
}
```

Comment: the problem is not because you are saving id to firestore but becuase of wrong syntax. check my answer [here] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74120758/how-can-i-save-messages-on-firestore-and-display-the-messages-on-screen?noredirect=1#comment130866977_74120758) on how to save a data with id to firestore.

Comment: Hey @john thanks for your contribution, but I think your answer on the other question was a little unclear to me. What do I do instead of the message id?

Comment: `String id = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('groups').doc().id;` this is not a valid syntax i dont know where you got this. you have to create your own unique id. because if you let firestore to assign a random id for you, you cant query that because you dont have a full control over that auto-generated id.

Comment: @john I used it for an earlier project and it worked. How should I store it?

Comment: i'm trying to help you to avoid future complications but if you want to go with auto generated id then there are two ways you can do that. 1. you can get the id upon submitting your data to firestore. 2. loop all the collection to be able to get the id. and for more info on this, check this similar qeustion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62348353/how-to-fetch-auto-generated-document-id-in-firebase-firestore-in-flutter)